# Netbeans cannot reload the plugins catalog because of connection error

Tags: netbeans

I'm trying to work with netbeans right now and I've run into a bit of trouble with installing plugins and resolving dependencies. Whenever I click the reload catalog button I get an error:

```
Unable to connect to the Certified Plugins because of Invalid argument: connect
```

I have proxy settings set to no proxy, have allowed the program through windows firewall, and can not find anything like this anywhere on google.

How should I go about fixing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 7.1.1, that's probably important. Sorry about that.

Comment: From the first part of your post I gues you installed new plugins. Which ones and from where?

Comment: I haven't installed any plugins because I haven't been able to reload the plugin catalog. I also haven't gone onto the web to install any.

Comment: That channel should point to "http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.1.1/uc/final/certified/catalog.xml.gz". Can you download that file with a browser (to discard network problems)?

Comment: Where should I put the downloaded catalog?

Comment: Still existing this problem on newly installed March 2019 version. Certified and update plugins not working, but `Plugin Portal` works OK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding -J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true into my netbeans.conf file, found deep in the depths of google from this http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Newly-installed-NB-7-won-t-connect-to-network-td4672870.html.

Comment: Oh. It was some sort of network problem after all, quite obscure.

Comment: As addition, This problem occured when I updated to NetBeans 7.4 and Upgrading Java to 1.7. The configuration file is found in `etc` folder of the NetBeans installtion folder and it is named as `netbeans.conf` Thank you for the solution

Comment: In addition I also had to allow Netbeans 8.1 through my firewall. Working behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but after I installed the **ProxySelector** , This issue was resolved.
[ProxySelector](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55258/proxyselector-v2)

Just download open plugins windows -> Downloaded (Tab) -> Add Plugins...

Enjoy !

Answer (score -2):

I was able to fix it by adding the plugin manually.

Copy the web address (where the plugin exist) from the error message. Then download it. You can then then add it using this path of Netbeans Tools > Plugins > Downloaded.